# How to connect to POP3 server through SSL with a custom TrustManager?

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, pop3, jakarta-mail

I am writing a test for an e-mail sender class and I need to be able to check if the message arrived, by downloading it from the target POP3 server. The server is an Exchange server and connection is only possible trough SSL. The test will periodically run on a CI server so the correct certification process is not possible. As far as I know it is possible to create a custom TrustManager class which can accept any certificate. How can I tell my POP3 connection to use my custom TrustManager?
I cannot see any way for it in current form of my code:

```
    String SSL_FACTORY = "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory";

    Properties pop3Props = new Properties();

    pop3Props.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.class", SSL_FACTORY);
    pop3Props.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
    pop3Props.setProperty("mail.pop3.port", "995");
    pop3Props.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.port", "995");

    URLName url = new URLName(provider, host, 995, "",
            username, password);

    Session session = Session.getInstance(pop3Props, null);
    Store store = new POP3SSLStore(session, url);
    store.connect();
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need a trust manager?

You could also import your certificate to jdk cacerts files, then the default TrustManager will accept your ssl connection to your site.

Here you have the link on how you should import your server certificate:

http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/03/add-list-certficates-java-keystore.html

Comment: Although it's quite easy to use a custom trust manager here (by passing a custom `SSLSocketFactory` that uses an `SSLContext` built with this trust manager), importing the test certificate into a trust store (default one or other) is the right approach.